# Mass Effect Upgrading Points for Sniper Rifles

Tags: mass-effect

I'm playing the first *Mass Effect*. I played it before but didn't complete it, and am going through it again. I enjoy playing games stealthily and attacking from distance if it's an option, so I chose my character to do that (I can't remember the name of it in the game). I specifically and purposely chose that, yet I am not at all able to upgrade his talent points for sniper; I can upgrade other things, but sniper is 1 of the few I can't upgrade.

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: You probably chose the wrong class.

Comment: I read through them and specifically chose the one that was about stealth and attacking from a distance.

Comment: Only as an Infiltrator or Soldier can you upgrade Sniper Rifle (unless you have unlocked the ability to add Sniper Rifle as a bonus skill).

Comment: Hmmm... I am certain Infiltrator is what I chose.

According to the wikia, they begin with light armour and eventually can wear medium armour, which I have unlocked. I have equipped medium armour, advanced shield boost, and the next one which increases damage reduction by 18% and increases hardening by 18%. The other 2 I can't upgrade are damping and first aid.

I am certain I chose that, unless I accidentally misclicked.

Comment: As Infiltrator you have to point several points into pistol before you can put points into sniper if I remember correctly.

Comment: Ohhh, if that's it then I'll have to try that. *has a look* Ha, yes. That's completely right. I didn't intend to use the pistol that much so I didn't bother looking, but after upgrading it with a few points one of the upgrades unlocks sniper rifles. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AdamP That's basically the answer, so maybe you should post an answer, not just a comment.

Comment: @Kareen I did so thank you. I originally posted it as just a comment because it has been quite some time since I played ME1 and I was not positive I was remembering correctly. And I was not in a situation where I could look up the wiki to be sure.

Answer (score 13):

As Infiltrator you have to put 5 points into pistol before you can put points into snipers.

This is true for several Infiltrator talents. Namely:

- Snipers → Unlocked at Pistols 5
- Fitness → Unlocked at Tactical Armor 6
- Damping → Unlocked at Electronics 4
- First Aid → Unlocked at Decryption 7

[Here](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Infiltrator) is a link to the Infiltrator wiki if you have any further questions about how the skills work.